# Page Redirection To Login on IIS

Tags: asp.net, redirect, webforms, iis-7

I am runnig asp.net website on my machine (IIS7).
In the web site (ASP.NET 3.5 WEBFORM) i developped a redirection to login page if session expired.

I installed my web site in another IIS. The redirection stop working !! i have no visibility on the new iis to see the configuration (prod envirennment)

**More explanation:**

i have a function Application_Error in global.asax which handle all errors and redirection in the application. when i run the website on my iis , the redirection work fine. When i run the websire in another server, the redirection stop working and i have a runtime error:

Details: see Attachements: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daOZg.png)

I precise  that the web.config doesnot contain the tag customErrors to force the application to pass throw Application_Error !

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What code you used for redirection logic? Can you explain what you mean  by two different IIS?

Comment: I add More explanation in the main message